# Colored line numbers with algorithmicx?

Tags: color, fancyvrb, algorithmicx

The `fancyvrb` allows me to customize line number style which I find very useful.  I'm using it to give line numbers a different color and then use that same color in the text describing the code.  I believe this makes it easier to locate the text describing a particular image.

[image: Colored line numbers example.]

Is there a way to do the same thing for pseudo code listings using `algorithmicx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to redefine what `\alglinenumber` does. More specifically, use something like

```
\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\color{<color>}\footnotesize#1:}
```

The following example was taken from the [`algorithmicx` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algpseudocode
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}

  \bigskip

\algrenewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\color{red!80!blue}\footnotesize#1:}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}

\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\alglinenumber` prints the entire line number construction, including the ending `:`. You can modify this to suit, if you don't want the separator.